# TypeScript type modification when using defaults and object destructuring assignment

Tags: typescript, default, destructuring

I ran into a strange case today using TypeScript (v3.5.1) that's left me puzzled. I defined an interface with an optional property but TypeScript allowed me to set the default to whatever I want when using object destructuring:

```
interface IFoo {
    letter?: "a" | "b" | "c";
}

const foo: IFoo = {};

const { letter = 1 } = foo;

console.log(letter); // --> 1
                     // Type signature of `letter`: "a" | "b" | "c" | 1
                     // Why does TS modify the type to include 1?
```

Run this code in the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDED2nkG8BQAkADYRiRQD8AXMgERx3IA+9ARk63QnQNz4BffPgSYQAZzDIY2WhmzIAvHgH8RYyXmSly0JcgCMyAfpmY1oiZlIA6YpgDmACh0UAlL2QB6L8gC0fgB8hvjIYeERkVE+yAAqAJ4ADijiwA4gcGAArlAomDDIAAau0IW0DJzsldyVBqFRDQ0xAOoAFvHIACaYEOJxAMrIALaYncAwHWCtKGBJMzigCMRZnSgGlEA).

Using some type inspection I noticed that TypeScript is modifying the expected  signature of `"a" | "b" | "c"` to `"a" | "b" | "c" | 1`. I was expecting to get a type error when I tried to default `letter` to `1`. Am I missing something here? Thanks!

Comment: Your expectation isn't warranted since you are declaring a new local variable. Furthermore, the behavior you expect would be detrimental.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The destructuring statement is introducing a new variable. It doesn't yet have a type unless one is assigned or in this case inferred.

Looking at the downcompiled code this becomes even more apparent:

```js
// const { letter = 1 } = foo;
var _a = foo.letter, letter = _a === void 0 ? 1 : _a;
```

Or to clean it up a bit:

```js
const letter = foo.letter === undefined ? 1 : foo.letter;
```

`letter` is either `foo.letter` or `1` if the former is undefined.

Comment: Yep.  You are creating a new variable named `letter`.  There is no rule that it has to have the same type as `foo.letter`

Answer (score 0):

That is the default behavior. If you want to prevent that and get an error, you should type the destructuring:

```
const { letter = 1 } : IFoo = foo; // "IFoo" added, this should show the error: Type '1' is not assignable to type '"a" | "b" | "c"'
```